# can I specify column names when creating a DataFrame

Tags: apache-spark

My data is in a `csv` file. The file hasn't got any header column

```
United States   Romania 15
United States   Croatia 1
United States   Ireland 344
Egypt   United States   15
```

If I read it, `Spark` creates names for the columns automatically.

```
scala> val data = spark.read.csv("./data/flight-data/csv/2015-summary.csv")
data: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [_c0: string, _c1: string ... 1 more field]
```

Is it possible to provide my own names for the columns when reading the file if I don't want to use `_c0`, `_c1`? For eg, I want `spark` to use `DEST`, `ORIG` and `count` for column names. I don't want to add header row in the `csv` to do this

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can, There is a way, You can us `toDF` function of dataframe.

```
val data = spark.read.csv("./data/flight-data/csv/2015-summary.csv").toDF("DEST", "ORIG", "count")
```

Answer (score 0):

It's better to define schema (`StructType`) first, then load the csv data using the schema.

Here is how to define schema:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
val schema = StructType(Array(
      StructField("DEST",StringType,true),
      StructField("ORIG",StringType,true),
      StructField("count",IntegerType,true)
    ))
```

Load the dataframe:

```
val df = spark.read.schema(schema).csv("./data/flight-data/csv/2015-summary.csv")
```

Hopefully it'll help you.